# Word for a member of a team who improves morale

Tags: single-word-requests

People in teams have names for their specialized roles: Medic, Navigator, Leader, Quartermaster, Cook, Ambassador, etc. What is the name for a person who's specialization is keeping the team's spirits high? A Bard kind of fits, but that's more intertwined with music.

Comment: *cheerleader*, *morale-booster*

Comment: Already considered cheerleader, its the closest so far, but not quite what I'm looking for

Comment: I've heard the term "morale officer", where "officer" is a tongue-in-cheek title that everyone knows doesn't mean anything.

Comment: If you're willing to consider "cheerleader", perhaps "pep squad" would work

Comment: Looking at your examples, maybe "Court Jester" would be a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do fine. It will be understood.

**Motivator** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/motivator)

> 1.1 A person who promotes interest in or enthusiasm for something:
>
> *"she was a great motivator of people and very energetic"*

I don't know if there's a specific title for a team's motivator.

Comment: This is the best proposed word so far, I'm going to give it another 24 hours, and accept it if nothing better comes up. Thanks, this word fits decently!

Answer (score 1):

The title **Social chair** applies to the member of an organization who plans the events. If there is a formal committee to plan the holiday party and happy hours, it's the leader of this committee.  If its informal, then you can use it loosely.

[The duties of a small business social chair](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/duties-social-chair-organization-18749.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to use :

mas•cot (ˈmæs kɒt, -kət)

n.
an animal, person, or thing adopted by a group as its symbol and bringer of good luck.

href="http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mascot">mascot